# SingalR performance counters with Azure SDK 2.6

Tags: asp.net, azure, signalr

There is a good article explaining how to enable SignalR performance counters on Azure web roles:

> [Using SignalR Performance Counters in an Azure Web Role](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/using-signalr-performance-counters-in-an-azure-web-role)

However, in Azure SDK 2.6 diagnostics through code is entirely deprecated (SignalRDiagnosticHelper class) and everything must be configured in xml file diagnostics.wadcfgx.

Does it mean that it is enough simply to move definitions of performance counters to the xml configuration file? If so, how should we be with dynamic category names? Or can this still lead to troubles due to diagnostics monitor starting before the role starts?

P.S. It would be also nice to have the asp.net article updated with the latest SDK 2.6 changes.

Comment: Can you file it on http://github.com/signalr/signalr ?

Comment: @Pawel, thanks, filed there as well. Will see where I would get the first reply and then will close the other one :)

Comment: I followed the same article and had the same problem. In my case, I just skipped the creating counters in code part. It is working now, I can see the SignalR metrics in perfmon when I RDP to the web role machine. I still did not get the metrics into the storage account.